# Failed convert string to Object using Eval()

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have a string like this

```
{
  recid: 1,
  QualHeadID: "1",
  Nomor: "1",
  Qualification: "Qualification",
  DetailQualification: "Detail Qualification",
  Unit: "Percentage",
  Target: "90.00 %",
  Actual: "90.00 %",
  Percentage: "100.00 %",
  CategoryWeight: "60.00 %",
  KpiScore: "60.00 %",
  Category: "Revenue",
  w2ui: {
    children: [{
      recid: 1007,
      QualHeadID: "1",
      Nomor: "1",
      DetailQualification: "Description"
    }]
  }
}, {
  recid: 2,
  QualHeadID: "1",
  Nomor: "2",
  Qualification: "Qualification 2",
  DetailQualification: "Detail Qualification 2",
  Unit: "Percentage",
  Target: "80.00 %",
  Actual: "89.00 %",
  Percentage: "111.25 %",
  CategoryWeight: "10.00 %",
  KpiScore: "11.13 %",
  Category: "Quality",
  w2ui: {
    children: [{
      recid: 1008,
      QualHeadID: "1",
      Nomor: "2",
      DetailQualification: "Description 2"
    }]
  }
}, {
  recid: 3,
  QualHeadID: "1",
  Nomor: "3",
  Qualification: "Qualification 3",
  DetailQualification: "Detail Qualification 3",
  Unit: "Percentage",
  Target: "85.00 %",
  Actual: "99.00 %",
  Percentage: "116.47 %",
  CategoryWeight: "30.00 %",
  KpiScore: "34.94 %",
  Category: "Internal",
  w2ui: {
    children: []
  }
}
```

and it works when I try to convert it to Object using Eval()

```
 var jsonQual = eval("[" + $("#lblQualification1").text() + "]");
```

however, with the same way I try to convert this string

```
{
  recid: 5,
  QualHeadID: "4",
  Nomor: "4",
  Qualification: "Competency - External",
  DetailQualification: "80% of customer score top-three-boxes score",
  Unit: "Percentage",
  Target: "70.00 %",
  Actual: "60.00 %",
  Percentage: "85.71 %",
  CategoryWeight: "50.00 %",
  KpiScore: "42.86 %",
  Category: "Quality",
  w2ui: {
    children: [{
      recid: 1011,
      QualHeadID: "4",
      Nomor: "4",
      DetailQualification: "80% dari total customer/company mengisi nilai 8,9 atau 10 dari range (1-10), di Nilai Total Penilaian Kepuasan Pelanggan (ex. Total customer selama periode review ada 10 cust, harus paling tidak 8 customer yang memberi nilai minimal 8) Apabila ada 7 orang memberi nilai 10, tetap ada 3 orang memberi nilai dibawah 8, dianggap tidak achieve Apabila dalam 1 company ada lebih dari 1 orang yang di survey, nilai dari company itu adalah rata2 nilai dari tiap orang yang disurvey Untuk yg Customer nya hanya 1 company, total customer berarti jumlah orang yang di survey dari company tsb"
    }]
  }
}, {
  recid: 6,
  QualHeadID: "4",
  Nomor: "5",
  Qualification: "Scoring Daily Activity",
  DetailQualification: "90% submitted on time",
  Unit: "Percentage",
  Target: "80.00 %",
  Actual: "60.00 %",
  Percentage: "75.00 %",
  CategoryWeight: "25.00 %",
  KpiScore: "18.75 %",
  Category: "Internal",
  w2ui: {
    children: [{
      recid: 1012,
      QualHeadID: "4",
      Nomor: "5",
      DetailQualification: "Each engineer must submit billable daily activity to timesheet application every Tuesday 10 AM and Friday 4 PM"
    }]
  }
}, {
  recid: 7,
  QualHeadID: "4",
  Nomor: "6",
  Qualification: "Self Development ",
  DetailQualification: "80% attending to workshop & English Course ",
  Unit: "Percentage",
  Target: "80.00 %",
  Actual: "90.00 %",
  Percentage: "112.50 %",
  CategoryWeight: "25.00 %",
  KpiScore: "28.13 %",
  Category: "Internal",
  w2ui: {
    children: [{
      recid: 1013,
      QualHeadID: "4",
      Nomor: "6",
      DetailQualification: "This qualification divided into two category. 2,5% for attending workshop and 2.5% for final score taken from English Course. If there is no workshop then 5% for English course"
    }]
  }
}
```

It doesnt work

Whats wrong with my string? Any rules that I betray from eval method? 
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: you can use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @azad OP can't use `JSON.parse()` - The string is not a valid JSON

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the second block of code. Try providing a [mcve] (your example is none of those three things). Preferably as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: yes, this is only a string not an JSON, actually I need this string to pass the value into the gridview records in w2ui.

Comment: @Quentin, my bad. Quick to respond. I was wrong. I tested both strings and they both seemed to work(they both have been converted correctly).

Comment: @Quentin really? It works?

Comment: @SeptianM — Two people have said that now.

Comment: @SeptianM, you say *It doesnt work*. But that could mean many things. Are there any errors? Can you provide a running snippet that replicates the problem you have? Please see the link provided by Quentin about how to create a running snippet. Hint: *use the* **<>** *button*.

Comment: @lonut thank you for answer, I get the error now, it string produce breakline when I generate it from database in the Details qualification Property, when I post it here, someone edited my string code, so my string format properly. Thank you in advace!

Comment: @SeptianM, I've edited your snippets, but it does not matter because I've tested with the first snippets you posted and the results are the same. Can't replicate your problem. As I've said before, creating a runnable snippet which replicates the problem you have would help us help you. So please do that and then we can talk business...Just FYI https://jsfiddle.net/w846tdvb/

Comment: @lonut oh ya I just reliaze that thank you. In my original string there is breakline, but I erase that before I post it.